# Is there a way to create a String resource file in javascript which I can use in my Vue code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get rid of all the hardcoded endpoints which I use with Axios. So I want to replace them to a resource file.

I have created a constants.js file and I import this file into my Vue component. When I refer to the value inside this file, I see that the String value from the constants.js file is undefined.

//this is the constants.js file

```
const endpoint_constants = {
    COMPANIES_ENDPOINT: "users/companies",
    SERVICES_ENDPOINT: "services",
    SERVICES_TYPE_ENDPOINT: "services/types",
    VENUES_ENDPOINT: "services/venues"
};
```

//this is inside my layout file.

```
import constants from "../constants.js"
   axios.get("http://localhost:8080/" + constants.SERVICES_TYPE_ENDPOINT)
                .then(response => (this.services = response.data))
                .catch(error => (console.log(error)));
```

I expect the String of the constants.js to be concatenated at the end of the URL, but I get back Undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export your object in constants.js file.

```
const endpoint_constants = {
    COMPANIES_ENDPOINT: "users/companies",
    SERVICES_ENDPOINT: "services",
    SERVICES_TYPE_ENDPOINT: "services/types",
    VENUES_ENDPOINT: "services/venues"
};
export default endpoint_constants
```

and then import it like,

```
import endpoint_constants from './constants.js';


axios.get("http://localhost:8080/" + endpoint_constants.SERVICES_TYPE_ENDPOINT)
                .then(response => (this.services = response.data))
                .catch(error => (console.log(error)));
```